# How to validate a field that is sent several times in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-orm, django-validation

I want to create a survey with django and ajax. In survey creation page, user can add several options for each survey. User may add 4 options, or add 10 options or any other number of options.
all the options are string and I want to validate them by `forms.CharField()`. So I created below `Form` for validating the them.

```
class SurveyOptionForm(forms.Form):
    option = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How can I validate more than one option by this form? or if there is any better way, what's that?

Comment: do you use foreignk key for that?

Comment: yes, I save surveys in a table and options in other table that first field of the options table is `ForeignKey(Surveys)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well for do that read more about [formset here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets) then you can use modelformset to save your option in the database [read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). Then you can add the option to survey like :

```
# don't save to the database
>>> instances = formset.save(commit=False)
>>> for instance in instances:
...     # do something with instance
...     option = instance.save(commit=False)
...     option.survey = your_suervey_object
...     option.save()
```

You can specify how many forms pass. You can use javascript to add a button which add or show another input